# How to submit BackboneJs models in html form post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am posting a form to a url from a page that displays **backbonejs** models.

This is how my backbonejs model looks like in the form:

**Form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="profit" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <div id="example-1-result" class="backgrid-container"></div>
    <button id="profit" name="profit" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

var Trade = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Trades = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Trade,
  url: "fodata"
});


var columns = [
 {
  name: "trade_id",
  label: "Trade Id",
  // The cell type can be a reference of a Backgrid.Cell subclass, any Backgrid.Cell subclass instances like *id* above, or a string
  cell: "string" // This is converted to "StringCell" and a corresponding class in the Backgrid package namespace is looked up
}, 
 {
  name: "order_id",
  label: "Order Id",
  // The cell type can be a reference of a Backgrid.Cell subclass, any Backgrid.Cell subclass instances like *id* above, or a string
  cell: "string" // This is converted to "StringCell" and a corresponding class in the Backgrid package namespace is looked up
}, 
{
  name: "trade_date",
  label: "Trade Date",
 cell: "datetime",
},
{
  name: "trade_time",
  label: "Trade Time",
  cell: "datetime",
},
{
  name: "contract_description",
  label: "Contract Description",
  cell: "string" // An integer cell is a number cell that displays humanized integers
}, 
{
  name: "expiry_date",
  label: "Expiry Date",
  cell: "datetime",
},
{
  name: "buy_quantity",
  label: "Buy Quantity",
  cell: "integer" // An integer cell is a number cell that displays humanized integers
}, {
  name: "buy_rate",
  label: "Buy Rate",
  cell: "number",
},
{
  name: "sale_quantity",
  label: "Sale Quantity",
  cell: "integer" // An integer cell is a number cell that displays humanized integers
}, {
  name: "sale_rate",
  label: "Sale Rate",
  cell: "number",
}
];

var trades = new Trades;

var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
      columns: columns,
      collection: trades
    });

// Initialize a new Grid instance
var refreshgrid = function(){
    $("#example-1-result").prepend(grid.render().$el);
}

 </script>
```

Now, while submitting, I need to submit the `trades` JSON data but I'm not able to get the model to submit.

How do I achieve this? Do I need to use backbonejs forms?

Comment: Is this the complete code? I dont see the Backbone.View that manages the form

Comment: I am not using a Backbone.View that manages the form. I'm using backgrid js that manages the data in the grid. I need to get the data out of the grid, the backbone model, and submit it in post.

Answer (score 1):

Backgrid is supposed to give you something to quickly edit all the models you give it to it (through the collection) using the normal backbone mechanisms. So technically, you shouldn't use a form to wrap it, and when editing each Trade model, the Trade model should be saved() after the end of the edit. Backgrid is a nice way to wrap basic CRUD on top of a resource.

If that's not the behavior you want, then maybe Backgrid isn't what you need?

That being said, nothing prevents you at anytime, no matter what's in the form, to do something like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event){
  //Don't send the form, stay on the page
  event.preventDefault();
  //Transform the collection of Trades into an array of JSONified Trade
  data = trades.map(function(trade){
    return trade.toJSON();
  });
  //Post this to the server
  $.post("url", {trades: data}, ... );
  return false;
});
```

But that seems odd.

If I misunderstood, maybe you can clarify your intent a bit? Hope this helps!

Comment: This might be a rather silly question, but how do I go on about posting the data and loading the url of the new rendered page which uses the data sent via post?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you are trying to do, more specifically how much of the page you want to update. If you want to update everything, including changing the URL of the current page, then it's probably easier to just drop the whole AJAX thing and send your form POST the normal way. If you want to use AJAX to just re-render part of it, then it all depends on what you can send back from your server: in the success call back of the $.post or $.ajax, you can get any kind of server reponse (pure HTML, JSON...). Need more details on what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: It'd be really odd to serialize a whole Backbone collection in a form that is sent the traditional way (with location changes and all that, as in the good old days) but it's technically feasible... You can always create hidden form elements before submitting with names like trades[0][name], trade[1][name], etc. On the server side, you'd receive an array of trades. But warning, this smells very funny!

Comment: The entire workflow is where I'm sending the submitting data to a url, which is different web page that gets rendered from the data that's submitted. Data being trades here.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to serialize the model and POST it.

See: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

If you .serialize the data you want and send that as part of your POST request it should work. Alternatively if you're looking for something a bit more advanced take a look at syphon:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/17/backbone-syphon-serialize-form-inputs-to-javascript-objects/

Serializing is most likely the key to what you want to achieve.